Unable to open file in Databricks DBFS
Without using spark or any other external tools, I'm trying to read following file from DBFS FileStore of Databricks. But the following code in a Databricks notebook gives error shown below. File has only few lines:
f = open('/dbfs/FileStore/tables/Test.csv', 'r')


FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/dbfs/FileStore/tables/Test.csv'

Question: What could be a cause of the issue, and how we can resolve it? This post did not help
Remarks: I'm using Databricks community edition. Same file successfully loads data into df:
df = spark.read.csv("/FileStore/tables/Test.csv", header=True, inferSchema=True)


I can confirm this behaviour in the Community Edition - I do not remember ever having this issue...When checking through the web terminal also - I am unable to see the folders under dbfs...very weird...

@AlexOtt A response from @AlexOtt here resolved the issue. I created a folder in the local system local system /databricks/driver/ and copied the file there. Please note that folders and files created in local system get wiped out when Cluster is terminated and or restarted.
